# Is there a difference between めんどうくさい and めんどくさい? (面倒くさい)

Tags: nuances

This is just a simple question, but I was wondering if there was a difference between めんどうくさい and めんどくさい. One has a う in it. I guess this also relate to others that are like this, is there a difference?

Answer (score 2):

めんどくさい is simply a colloquial variant of めんどうくさい. In formal situations, めんどうくさい or めんどうな is preferred. But in highly formal or academic contexts, objective phrases like 時間を要する or 煩雑な would be better.

Comment: I think there is a type: "In informal situations" not "In formal situations"

Comment: @Kimbi I mean it. めんどうくさい is more formal, and めんどくさい is informal.